# Multi condition filter in R

Tags: r

Im trying to filter data by filter function. The problem is there are 2 conditions which I don't know how to combine. For example: Filter the created date just in February 2020.

```
Feb <- CheckinHistory %>% filter( Date >= "2020-02-01" && "Date <= 2020-02-31") %>% select(CustomerID,Date)
```

R says about unabigious. Can anyone help me, thank you a lot!

Comment: replace `"Date <= 2020-02-31"` by `Date <= "2020-02-31"`

Comment: My bad in writting, fixed it as what you said. However, Feb <- CheckinHistory %>% filter( Date >= "2020-02-01" && Date <= "2020-02-31") %>% select(CustomerID,Date)
Error: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
x character string is not in a standard unambiguous format. It still doesn't work >'<

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no date as `2020-02-31`. Try the following -

```
library(dplyr)

Feb <- CheckinHistory %>% 
        mutate(Date = as.Date(Date)) %>%
        filter(Date >= as.Date("2020-02-01") & Date <= as.Date("2020-02-29")) %>%
        select(CustomerID,Date)
```

Comment: Hi, I applied your code. It works, but now Feb: 0 obs. of 2 variable while in fact, there is data in February ToT. as.Date(CheckinHistory$Date, format = "%y/%m/%d") is it because I formated the data like this?

Comment: What are first few values of `CheckinHistory$Date` ?

Comment: 2020-11-24
2020-12-05
2020-11-17
2020-12-04
2020-12-15
2020-12-22
2020-11-08
2020-10-18
2020-12-02
2020-11-17
2020-11-23
2020-10-04
2020-12-28
2020-08-07
2020-07-17
2020-12-20
2020-09-29
2020-07-14
2020-06-16
2020-06-09
2020-07-02
well, it works for January when I code Jan <- CheckinHistory %>% filter(Date <= "2020-01-31") %>% select(CustomerID,Date). I stuck at Feb.

Comment: Are you copying code in the answer as it is ? Is your data grouped? Try ungrouping the data `CheckinHistory %>%  ungroup %>% mutate(Date = as.Date(Date)) ......`

Comment: God! Thank you. It works. Can you explain to me why I have to ungroup the data

Comment: You must have grouped your data earlier with some column. So `filter` is looking only in that group hence it fails by ungrouping we are looking for the dates in the entire dataframe.